# Solve quaternion kinematic

Tags: kinematics

In a robot or spacecraft attitude representation, using quaternion is relevant.
The kinematic equation is as below

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{q}_0 \\ \dot{q}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-q^\top \\ q_0\,I_3 + q^\times
\end{bmatrix} \omega=H(q) \omega
$$

is there any way to solve this equation based on $\omega$ and $q$?
actually I want to integrate the quaternion, but the nonlinear property of the equation makes it hard and complicate.

edit:
as @fibonatic proved in [this post](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/42901/32367),
$$
\omega = 4\,H(q)^\top \dot{\textbf{q}}
$$
so we can write
$$
\omega.dt= 4\,H(q)^\top .d\textbf{q}
$$
but I can't integrate $4\,H(q)^\top$ respect to $\textbf{q}$, because $\textbf{q}$ is a vector and I don't know how integrate based on a vector.

---

explaining why I want to do above calculation:

in a robotic problem I have below kinematic and dynamic equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{\textbf{q}} = H\omega
\\
\dot{\omega} = -J^{-1} \omega^\times J \omega  + J^{-1} u = f(\omega)  + J^{-1} u
\end{cases}
\qquad \qquad  (1)
$$
the input %u% is designed such that, $\omega$ and $\textbf{q}$ follow a desired values, $\omega_{d}$ and $\textbf{q}_{d}$
//
in a complicated process, I have define new $\Omega$
$$
\Omega = \nu(\omega)
$$

which $\nu$ is a nonlinear function of $\omega$. I rederive the kinematic and dynamic equations for new $\Omega$
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{\textbf{q}_{new}} = H(q_{new})\Omega
\\
\dot{\Omega} = g(\omega)  + J^{-1} u
\end{cases}
\qquad \qquad  (2)
$$
which $\nu(\omega)$ is a nonlinear function of $\omega$. as you see, I have new quaternion calculation which differs from real quaternion in $equation (1)$. if we want to $\textbf{q}_{new}$ to reach $\textbf{q}_{d}$, it create steady state error in real quaternion, $\textbf{q}$. therefore, I should change the desired value of new quaternion, $\textbf{q}_{new\ d}$ such than real quaternion,$\textbf{q}$ reaches desired value $\textbf{q}_{d}$.

to find the $\textbf{q}_{new\ d}$, I should calculate $\dot{\textbf{q}_{new}} = H(q_{new})\Omega$

I wish, you understand what I want to calculate.

Comment: Can you clarify if the input (values that you have at the beginning) are `q(0)` and `w(t)` and you want to find q(t) ? Then the problem is one dimensional integration based on the variable `t`. Is it enough to find the result q(t) numerically ? Then the problem is quite straightforward.

Comment: @AJN, in a problem, I have a virtual $\omega$ which differs slightly from real $\omega$. when I put the virtual $\omega$ to kinematic, gets virtual quaternion. I use matlab for simulation. I want to path planning for virtual quaternion based on real quaternion path, $\omega$ and t. I want to solve the kinematic analytically not using matlab numerical solver.

Comment: in this problem, we have the instant value of the parameters and the initial values, $\omega(0)$, $q(0)$, $\omega(current)$, $q(current)$ and $t$. do you see the comment I wrote for Mike? I have explain the problem and why I want to calculate %q%.

Comment: calculating (integrating) the kinematic equation is completely mathematical problem. I said the application to clarify why I want to do that.

Comment: "*if we want to qnew to reach qd, it create steady state error in real quaternion, q*". In most practical scenarios, the steady state error is not solved by using an adjusted target, but using some type of integral term in the controller. But you are solving kinematics, i wonder why there should be a steady error.

Comment: Why don't you want to follow a numerical integration scheme?  It is usually the practical choice for most $\omega(t)$ profiles. Why can't you numerically intergrate $\dot{q}_{new} = H(q_{new})\Omega$ to find $q_{new,d}$?

Comment: actually, solving the problem you said is challenging and I want to find a solution. in practical I see that I have steady state in real q. I wanted to make a closed form for calculating qdnew.

Comment: If you are particular about closed form solutions, try asking this at one of the math.SE sites.

Comment: [Searching for quaternions at mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=quaternions) is a possibility per Solar Mike. Also try [Searching for quaternions at robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/search?q=quaternions), drones use quat's a lot. Spacecraft also, I suppose that would be physics?

Comment: @PeteW some dork deleted my comment, but left another saying the same thing... go figure.