# inverse kinematic of modified Rodriquez parameters

Tags: robotics, kinematics

as you know, the attitude of a robot is represented using many ways, euler angles, quaternion, rodriquez parameters, and so on. I should use rodriquez representation in a problem formulated same as a robotic problem.

the kinematic based on rodriquez parameters are defined as below:

[image]

I want to have $\omega$ formulation based on $\dot{p}$. is there any way to calculate it analytically?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but matrix inversion formula for sum of matrices may be of interest if you don't get an answer. [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275008/simplest-representation-of-the-inverse-of-an-identity-matrix-plus-a-positive-mat), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298616/what-is-inverse-of-ia).

Comment: Can you tell us the use case of inverting this formula. Perhaps there is a work around (numerical or analytic) that would suit your application.

Comment: thank you @AJN, actually I want it to use it in designing closed loop control law. about the quaternion, Fibonatic has helped me in [_this post_](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42892/inverse-of-quaternion-kinematic-matrix), but unity property of quaternion can not be satisfied in control law design. so I switched to MRP.

Comment: **1** I don't know why unity property of quaternion can not be satisfied in control law. There are published results which use quaternion based control laws AFAIK. **2** In the practical application, there will be a device which converts / integrates angular velocity to the Rodrigues parameters using the above formula. So the control system designer wanting to reconstruct $\omega$ from $\dot{p}, p$ is surprising. Please add a good description of the various parts of your control system / plant. **3** In case you don't get an answer here, ask the moderators to migrate this to math.SE.